# Function from integers to integers

Tags: combinatorics

Can there exist an $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that the following holds.

If $(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ be such that $f(m) \leq n$, then $f(m+1)\leq n$ and $f(m-1)\leq n+1$?

If exists can we characterize it? If I take $f$ to be just decreasing then first condition is easily satisfied but the second is not. The same in the reverse form if I take $f$ to be just increasing.

Comment: There exists such functions,. Take, for example,  $f(n)=0$ for all $n$

Comment: any nontrivial example? Can we characterize what are all such functions?

Comment: Suppose you pick $m$ first, then what value of $n$ gives the tightest restrictions on $f$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem. Otherwise it looks like you are asking others to do your homework for you.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Suppose you have a function $f$ and want to check it satisfies this property. Suppose further that you've picked some arbitrary numbers, say $(m,n)=(4,10)$, and found that $f(4)\le10$ and that the property holds true. What can you then say about the property when looking at the numbers $(m,n)=(4,11)$?

Comment: So if $(m,n)$ be such that $f(m)\leq n$ and satisfies the conditions, then the pair $(m,n+1)$ will satisfy again all the properties and we can go recursively with the only the increment in $n$. But still how can I guess an $f$?

Comment: You can't "guess an f" until you examine what the property means. So now you know that larger values of $n$ will take care of themselves, for a given value for $m$ what value of $n$ would be the most important one to check?

Comment: So we need to check those $n$ such that $n \leq m$? Am I right?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis  I could find one class of such functions . Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such $f$ is decreasing and $f(m-1) \leq f(m)+1$. But $f$ is decreasing implies $f(m-1)- f(m)\geq 0$. So either $f(m-1) = f(m)+1$ or $f(m-1) =f(m)+1$. In the first case $f$ is constant . I am not sure whether these are the only such functions.

Comment: For each $m$, either $f(m-1) = f(m)$ or $f(m-1) = f(m)+1$, but $f$ does not have to make the same choice between these two options for every $m$. For example, it could be that $f(-1) = f(0)$ but $f(-2) = f(-1) + 1$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair ya that is correct. i am wrong in the second statement. But these are the only functions?

Comment: $f$ will satisfy your condition if and only if for all $m, (f(m-1) = f(m)\text{ or }f(m-1) = f(m) + 1)$. Turning it around, this is: for all $m, (f(m) = f(m-1)\text{ or }f(m) = f(m-1) - 1)$. Now consider the function $g(m) = f(m-1) - f(m)$. What must be true of $g$? If you are given an arbitrary function $g$ satisfying that restriction, can you find a function $f$ that produces it? And if two different $f$ give the same function $g$, how can they differ from each other (i.e., what else do you need to know to recover $f$ from $g$)?

Comment: $g$ will satisfy that $g(m)=0$ or $1$ for all $m$. Now given such a $g$, I tried to define $f$ as follows. I have chosen an integer $k$ arbitrarily and set as basis case $f(0)=k$. Then I defined $f(1)=f(0)-g(0), f(2)=f(1)-g(1),\cdots, f(-1)=f(0)+g(0), f(-2)=f(-1)+g(-1)\cdots$. Now if there are two different $f$ and $f'$ which give same $g$, then for each $m$, $f(m-1)-f(m)=f'(m-1)-f'(m)$. I could not proceed further.